# Сбой после помещения данных запросов в setText() и для всех setText() в QT Designer.... как это исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, pyqt6

Я делаю админ панель для себя и я хочу чтобы по нажатию кнопки мне выводило цену предметов на данный момент. но у меня крашит скрипт при попытке использовать setText(). Как это исправить?
main.py

```
        from PyQt6 import uic, QtWidgets
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
    from PyQt6.uic.properties import QtWidgets
    from requests import *
    from SimpleQIWI import *
    from auth_token import token, phone
    import webbrowser
    from CasePrices import *
    from FAFTUI import *
    import sys
    
    Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("FAFTUI.ui")
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    form = Form()
    form.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    
    
    class Main(QDialog, Ui_FAFTUI):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Main, self).__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
    
    
    class Child(QDialog, Ui_CasePrices):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Child, self).__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
    
        def OPEN(self):
            self.show()
    
    
    
    
    api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)
    networse = form.networse_2.alignment()
    percent2 = 5.5
    price2 = networse * percent2 / 100
    percent1 = 5 + (price2 * 10 / 100)
    percent3 = 1
    price1 = networse * percent1 / 100
    price3 = networse * percent3 / 100
    user1 = '@twisttyy'
    user2 = '@sashok'
    user3 = '@invalid_na...'
    
    
    def recoil():
        req = requests.get(
            'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=5&market_hash_name=Recoil Case')
        responce = req.json()
        info = responce["lowest_price"]
        ui.prb1.setText(info)
        print(info)
    
    
    def fracture():
        req = requests.get(
            'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=5&market_hash_name=Fracture Case')
        responce = req.json()
        info = responce["lowest_price"]
        ui.prb2.setText()
        print(info)
    
    
    def snakebite(self):
        req = requests.get(
            'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=5&market_hash_name=Snakebite Case')
        responce = req.json()
        info = responce["lowest_price"]
        ui.prb3.setText(info)
        print(info)
    
    
    def DNS():
        req = requests.get(
            'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=5&market_hash_name=Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case')
        responce = req.json()
        info = responce["lowest_price"]
        print(info)
    
    
    def clutch():
        req = requests.get(
            'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=5&market_hash_name=Clutch Case')
        responce = req.json()
        info = responce["lowest_price"]
        print(info)
    
    
    def prisma2():
        req = requests.get(
            'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=5&market_hash_name=Prisma 2 Case')
        responce = req.json()
        info = responce["lowest_price"]
        print(info)
    
    
    def babkivsem():
        api.pay(account="+79167706785", amount=price1, comment='Ваш Доход с фермы!')
        api.pay(account="+79256523786", amount=price2, comment='Ваш Доход с фермы!')
        api.pay(account="+79031380675", amount=price3, comment='Ваш Доход с фермы!')
    
    
    def babki1():
        api.pay(account="+79167706785", amount=price1, comment='Ваш Доход с фермы!')
        print(price1, 'Отправлены', user1)
    
    
    def babki2():
        api.pay(account="+79256523786", amount=price2, comment='Ваш Доход с фермы!')
        print(price1, 'Отправлены', user2)
    
    
    def babki3():
        api.pay(account="+79031380675", amount=price3, comment='Ваш Доход с фермы!')
        print(price1, 'Отправлены', user3)
    
    
    def tg1():
        webbrowser.open('https://t.me/ZiFlux', new=0)
    
    
    def tg2():
        webbrowser.open('https://t.me/csgofarmbot', new=0)
    
    
    def tg3():
        webbrowser.open('https://t.me/csgocasefarmbot', new=0)
    
    
    
    ch = Child()
    
    form.PriceButton.clicked.connect(ch.OPEN)
    form.pushButton_13.clicked.connect(tg1)
    form.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(tg2)
    form.pushButton_12.clicked.connect(tg3)
    form.client1.clicked.connect(babki1)
    form.client2.clicked.connect(babki2)
    form.client3.clicked.connect(babki3)
    form.PriceButton.clicked.connect(recoil)
    form.PriceButton.clicked.connect(fracture)
    form.PriceButton.clicked.connect(snakebite)
    form.PriceButton.clicked.connect(DNS)
    form.PriceButton.clicked.connect(clutch)
    form.PriceButton.clicked.connect(prisma2)
    app.exec()
```

CasePrices.py

```
        # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\irsha\PycharmProjects\FAFT\CasePrices.ui'
    #
    # Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.3.1
    #
    # WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
    # run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.
    
    
    from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
    
    class Ui_CasePrices(object):
        def setupUi(self, CasePrices):
            CasePrices.setObjectName("CasePrices")
            CasePrices.resize(371, 461)
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\Users\\irsha\\PycharmProjects\\FAFT\\icon.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.State.Off)
            CasePrices.setWindowIcon(icon)
            CasePrices.setStyleSheet("QDialog {\n"
    "    background-color: #232323;\n"
    "}")
            self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(CasePrices)
            self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 209, 461))
            self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
            self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.label_2.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 40px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.label_4.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
            self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.label_3.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
            self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.label_5.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
            self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.label_6.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)
            self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.label_7.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_7)
            self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(CasePrices)
            self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 60, 131, 411))
            self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
            self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
            self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
            self.prb1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
            self.prb1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 100px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover {\n"
    "    background-color: orange;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "    background-color: yellow;\n"
    "}")
            self.prb1.setObjectName("prb1")
            self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prb1)
            self.prb2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
            self.prb2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover {\n"
    "    background-color: orange;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "    background-color: yellow;\n"
    "}")
            self.prb2.setObjectName("prb2")
            self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prb2)
            self.prb3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
            self.prb3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover {\n"
    "    background-color: orange;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "    background-color: yellow;\n"
    "}")
            self.prb3.setObjectName("prb3")
            self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prb3)
            self.prb4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
            self.prb4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover {\n"
    "    background-color: orange;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "    background-color: yellow;\n"
    "}")
            self.prb4.setObjectName("prb4")
            self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prb4)
            self.prb4_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
            self.prb4_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover {\n"
    "    background-color: orange;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "    background-color: yellow;\n"
    "}")
            self.prb4_2.setObjectName("prb4_2")
            self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prb4_2)
            self.prb5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
            self.prb5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 14px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover {\n"
    "    background-color: orange;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "    background-color: yellow;\n"
    "}")
            self.prb5.setObjectName("prb5")
            self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prb5)
            self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(CasePrices)
            self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 0, 131, 61))
            self.label_8.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
    "    background-color: gold;\n"
    "    width: 75px;\n"
    "    height: 50px;\n"
    "    font-size: 40px;\n"
    "    font-weight: bold;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    text-align: center;\n"
    "}\n"
    "")
            self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
    
            self.retranslateUi(CasePrices)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(CasePrices)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, CasePrices):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            CasePrices.setWindowTitle(_translate("CasePrices", "Dialog"))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "    Кейс"))
            self.label.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "Гремучий кейс:"))
            self.label_4.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "Кейс Разлом:"))
            self.label_3.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "Змеиный укус:"))
            self.label_5.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "Кейс Грёзы и Кошмары:"))
            self.label_6.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "Кейс Решающий момент:"))
            self.label_7.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "Призма 2 Кейс:"))
            self.prb1.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "PushButton"))
            self.prb2.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "PushButton"))
            self.prb3.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "PushButton"))
            self.prb4.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "PushButton"))
            self.prb4_2.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "PushButton"))
            self.prb5.setText(_translate("CasePrices", "PushButton"))
            self.label_8.setText(_translate("CasePrices", " Цена"))
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        CasePrices = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_CasePrices()
        ui.setupUi(CasePrices)
        CasePrices.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

auth_token.py - просто апи + номер телефона для либов
P.S. Я начал изучать QT 2 дня назад, и мне очень жаль, если мой код такой ужасный.
Если нужен FAFTUI.py напишите об этом.

Comment: Да, ваше приложение не возможно проверить и к тому же
ваш приведенный код отформатирован не правильно.
Вам  надо составить  [mcve], 
который демонстрирует проблему. 
Запустите ваш код в CMD/консоли/терминале и получите реальную ошибку  
и покажите эту ошибку полностью.

Comment: А также ответьте на вопросы:
О каком сбое вы говорите: 
"Сбой после помещения данных запросов в `setText()`". 
Покажите данные, которые вы вставляете в какой-то виджет 
(что это за виджет?) и какой тип имеют эти данные.

Как понимать: "... для всех `setText()` в `QT Designer` ..." ?

"... крашит скрипт при попытке использовать `setText()`" - 
покажите строку и ошибку, которую вы получаете.